# Gulp: can I store different parts of the pipeline in variables before returning the final pipeline?

Tags: gulp

I need to build a gulp pipeline that may conditionally include certain steps. Let’s say, I want to add a header to the top of my files for production but not for development environment, or something like that. Is it OK to build the first, common, part of the pipe, store it in a variable, then check for a certain condition and depending on it build the rest of the pipe like so:

```
function buildCSS() {
    var processors = [
        atImport,
        cssnano
    ];

    var stylesTargetDirectory = path.join(global.paths.buildDirectory, 'styles')

    var lessToCss = gulp.src(global.paths.lessMain)
        .pipe(less({
            paths: [ global.paths.stylesDirectory ]
        }))
        .pipe(postcss(processors))

    var result = foo === 'bar' ? // a condition I am checking for
        lessToCss.pipe(header('hello world') // this is gulp-header
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stylesTargetDirectory)) :
        lessToCss
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stylesTargetDirectory))

    return result;
}
```

it works fine for individual tasks but I am just a bit scared that it will bit me when I start combining tasks. This way of building a pipeline dynamically looks just too good to be true, because if it is OK, then I do not understand the purpose of using `gulp-if` or `lazypipe`. Which I would prefer to avoid if possible, because they are temperamental and are breaking my tasks.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using gulp-if (https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if). It will either pass your stream onto the desired task or skip and pass it along to the next task. See their examples for more info.